# Intellisense/documentation of WIA constants and values

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wia

Looking at the WIA driver documentation for the [WIA_IPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552593(v=vs.85).aspx) property, the valid values are listed as:

- BACK_FIRST
- BACK_ONLY
- DUPLEX
- FRONT_FIRST
- FRONT_ONLY

Just the names, no values.

The documentation of the properties from the application developer's perspective ([WIA_IPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552593(v=vs.85).aspx) looks the same.

If I want to write the following code, using WIA Automation and VB.NET (could just as easily be in C#):

```vb
Dim manager = New DeviceManager
Dim deviceinfo = manager.DeviceInfos.Cast(Of DeviceInfo).First() 'Assuming there is an available device
Dim device = deviceinfo.Connect
device.Properties(WIA_IPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT).Value = FRONT_FIRST
```

I cannot do so, because these constants are not available from the WIA Automation layer, and therefore not available from Intellisense.

I can define specific constants that I need, or use magic numbers when I know them:

```
device.Properties(3088).Value = ???
```

How can I get these constants in Intellisense without defining them myself, or where is there documentation for the values of these constants?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
Public Class Const_WIA

    Public Const WIA_RESERVED_FOR_NEW_PROPS As UInt32 = 1024
    Public Const WIA_DIP_FIRST As UInt32 = 2
    Public Const WIA_DPA_FIRST As UInt32 = WIA_DIP_FIRST + WIA_RESERVED_FOR_NEW_PROPS
    Public Const WIA_DPC_FIRST As UInt32 = WIA_DPA_FIRST + WIA_RESERVED_FOR_NEW_PROPS '
    '       //
    '       // Scanner only device properties (DPS)
    '       //
    Public Const WIA_DPS_FIRST As UInt32 = WIA_DPC_FIRST + WIA_RESERVED_FOR_NEW_PROPS
    Public Const WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_STATUS As UInt32 = WIA_DPS_FIRST + 13
    Public Const WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT As UInt32 = WIA_DPS_FIRST + 14
End Class
```

[here's](https://asprise.com/scan/files/docs/javadoc/constant-values.html) a list with matching values

Comment: The link you provided is Asprise's documentation of their library's constants, which mirror the WIA constants. I was looking for Microsoft documentation / Intellisense.

Comment: @ZevSpitz has you wish but they are the same. they took the one from microsoft and put it in their docs.